# Checkmark "✔" look different in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css

I am trying to use "✔" as Pseudo element to indicate item has been selected,
but problem is "✔" shows in green in Microsoft Edge

```
.selected:before{
  content:"✔";
  position:absolute;
  font-size:20px;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

Please check this pen
https://codepen.io/kaleem78/pen/WKMwqG

How to make "✔" to look same on all the browsers?

Comment: Everything is different in Microsoft... I think you should use a standard icon like `Fontawesome` or something like that

Comment: ^^ I second Fontawesome, after begrudgingly being forced to use it a while ago (and have since adopted it for all projects after), or simply use an image.

Comment: @Mr.Web only for checkmark, i cant load the fontawesome css file. it will increase the load time.

Comment: @KaleemNalband So load only the checkmark...

Comment: do you use any laibry like:bootstrap?

Comment: Choose custom fonts only: http://fontello.com/

Comment: @Archer I am expecting a CSS fix for this.

Comment: There are a couple of other symbols you could use. "Check Mark" instead of "Heavy Check Mark" seems pretty consistent: https://www.alt-codes.net/check-mark-symbols.php

Comment: Sadly, you can't resolve all browser differences with CSS. If you're going to be stubborn (no offence meant) then you're not going to be satisfied.  Using a png as a background image will 100% resolve the issue.

Comment: @KaleemNalband download the svg from font awsome and use it

Comment: Maybe use this instead: __✓__. This looks normal in Edge. Your version is the heavy checkmark and somehow Edge decided that it should be shown as a green checkmark.

Comment: @לבנימלכה i am not using any libraries.

Comment: @ChanMT, Thank you, "✓" this check mark worked.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, ya, content:"✔\fe0e"  also works.

Comment: I didn't know anyone uses Microsoft Edge until I read this.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this code to your :before state:

```
font-family: arial, Segoe UI Symbol;
```